# How to generate uniq namespace from a geven string?

Tags: php, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I tried to assign automatically a XMLNS from PHP namespace but the namespace in PHP is so long and I don't want to send to client side a structure of my app... example:

Namespace in PHP = `crux\hci\cli\msg_sys\presenters`

And in HTML tag: `<html xmlns:crux_hci_cli__msg_sys_presenters='zz'>`

So how to convert `crux_hci_cli__msg_sys_presenters` to `khgs12so7` for example?

NB: `khgs12so7` must be the same even if the PHP class was invoked many times...

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of hash function like e.g. `hash('algo', 'your namespace')`
Use a hash algo which produces some short strings. You can see all available hash algos with `hash_algos()`

Comment: ok great thank, just one question please, there is many (algo) in hash_algos() list, do you know if ther is one that output s a short string, md5 or sha... have a so long output...?